# "line 168: Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'."

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a crypto trading strategy in TradingView, and everything was going well until my script decided to upgrade to v5. Everything works, but when I add these two lines, I get the above error.

There are no extra spaces, tabstops or anything else and I am very confused and irritated.

Lines:

```
strategy.entry(id="Enter Long", strategy.long, when=LongOpenConditions)
strategy.entry(id="Enter Short", strategy.short, when=ShortOpenConditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out "id=" wasn't supposed to be there. It threw the wrong error. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you start using argument names in the function call, you must continue using other argument's names too after that point.

All below should compile fine.

```
strategy.entry(id="Enter Long", direction=strategy.long, when=LongOpenConditions)
strategy.entry("Enter Long", direction=strategy.long, when=LongOpenConditions)
strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, when=LongOpenConditions)
```